# google maps problem

Tags: google-maps

i am doing online food ordering project. the restaurants register and create zones, these shows that how much long this restaurant delivery food items, my problem is how to create zones in google map. and when company emplyee open his company it must shows the near restaurant (based on zones). is it possible. can anyone have please help me.

sorry for my poor english.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is overlays.

Have a look at this section of the documentation (v3)
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons

Basically you'll want to define a polygon that is the zone. You can also colour and label the polygon.

Comment: thanks for replay, i want to create circles(restaurant owners create zones as circle) dynamically(means draw circle on map).

Comment: restaurant as center point owner create circle. example he want to create circle based on kilometers take kilometrs as radies draw the the ciecle.

Comment: Ah, circles are harder. have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825794/draw-radius-around-a-point-in-google-map

Comment: hi i am still strugling to create circles. do you have any other idea.

Comment: Try Google. The search 'draw circles google maps' had heaps of results.