# How to draw a circle in google-map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to draw a circle in google-map at a certain position(other than center), provided user has latitude, longitude and radius?

Comment: First google result: http://blog.enbake.com/draw-circle-with-google-maps-api-v3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Create marker 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(53, -2.5),
  title: 'Some location'
});

// Add circle overlay and bind to marker
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 16093,    // 10 miles in metres
  fillColor: '#AA0000'
});

circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

Sounds like if you have the lat/long and the radius you want then you can just define a point somewhere on the map, then bind a circle to that point.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825794/draw-radius-around-a-point-in-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle)!

```
google.maps.CircleOptions
```