# find radius from given miles/kilometer In google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, math

I want to Draw a circle with  given latitude and longitude
["lat":51.41714046916216,"lng":-2.3588300000000095]   in google map   with 22 miles area.

How can i find radius from  given miles/kilometer 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825794/draw-radius-around-a-point-in-google-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Circle area:**

```
area=PI*radius^2
```

so:

```
radius=sqrt(area/PI)
PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
```

area is in the same units as radius !!!

Well if you have already 2D orthonormal coordinate system then this is OK but if not (X axis units are different then Y axis units and nonlinear) then this formula will not work properly. In that case the circle area must be projected from orthonormal space back to your Ellipsoid surface projection.

For that you have to add more info. However for small enough surfaces it can be simplified by ellipse. Also the target accuracy is a relevant information for this.

Comment: I think area = `Pi * r ^2`, not `2 * Pi * r^2`

Comment: @Mark Setchell yes of coarse where was my head :)

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the area of a circle is

```
A = Pi * radius * radius
```

so the radius is

```
r = sqrt(area/Pi)
```

so in your case

```
r = sqrt(22/3.1415)
```

so

```
r = 2.64 miles or 4.25 km
```

Note that this is approximate because the formula is based on flat surfaces, and the Earth's surface obviously isn't flat, but it will not be that great a difference for relatively small areas like yours.